# Any developer side gotchas after a Skuid deployment?

Tags: appexchange, skuid

Curious from a developers perspective what sort of gotchas anyone has had in deploying Skuid.

**Specifically:** Has the dev team run into any major blockers after a deployment of Skuid in an Org?

Note: I realize that some Skuid devs are active members here, and I am quite impressed with their product so far, but I was just hoping to get a realistic real world issues that might come along with a Skuid deployment in our SF Org.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you contact Skuid customers directly. There are many reviews on the AppExchange and folks are pretty easy to find in the Skuid Community at http://community.skuidify.com. If you need some real-world contacts, Skuid would be happy to provide them, including some folks doing very large deployments.